# Group By でまとめられた後に、特定の値が含まれているか true or false で返したい

Tags: mysql, sql

**samples table**

```
id, A, B
1,  1, 1
2,  1, 2
3,  1, 3
4,  1, 3
5,  2, 1
```

上のようなテーブルに対して、

AでGroup byした状態で、Bに2が含まれている場合は、true、含まれていない場合はfalseを返すようなSQLを書きたいです

**レスポンス例**

```
A, contains
1, true
2, false
```

どのようにすれば、上記が満たせるSQLが書けるでしょうか？

Comment: [How to determine if a value appears in a GROUP BY group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545932) が参考になるかと思います。`SELECT A, IF(SUM(B = 2), 'true', 'false') AS contains FROM samples GROUP BY A;`

Comment: 出来ました！ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 1):

(コメントより)

[How to determine if a value appears in a GROUP BY group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545932) が参考になるかと思います。

```
SELECT A, IF(SUM(B = 2), 'true', 'false') AS contains FROM samples GROUP BY A;
```